# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error in Angular4 using Spring Boot Rest Api

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot

This is the service.ts code. I am using server side REST API to authenticate 
   a username and password. Even after the CORS is present in the server side 
   the error still persists. If anyone knows what i am doing worng help me and 
   thanks in advance.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

 @Injectable()

 export class Service {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

   authenticate(model) {
   var creds = "name=" + model.email + "&password=" + model.password;
   console.log(creds)
   var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

   return new Promise(resolve => {
       this.http.post('http://sample.sample.com/api/authenticate', creds, {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
           if(data.json().success){
               resolve(true);
           }
           else
               resolve(false);
       });
   });
   }

   }
```

Comment: Show us 'the server side'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var creds = {"name":model.email,"password" : model.password};
```

You need to pass the data like this.

```
   this.http.post('http://sample.sample.com/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify(creds), {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable CORS on Server/in your API, this error occurs when CORS is not enabled.